# Bootstrap with Internet Explorer in compability view

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I'm working with a customisable software where the html code is autogenerated. The only code allowed to be written is javascript.

As the generated screens are not the most modern and responsive, I've started to include some jquery in order to manipulate the autogenerated html (I mean the DOM of course...).

A sexy idea would be to use the bootstrap framework. After some tests I've some good results with Firefox.

But I'm stuck with Internet Explorer: the web application has to be used in compatibility view (otherwise it's not usable), but the rendering of the bootstrap elements is bad (css are not applied etc etc... but working well if I'm not in compatibility view).

I tried different solutions like adding meta tags but no way, it doesn't give results.

Sure that some of you would have some ideas / advice?

Comment: What version of bootstrap and what IE compatibility version? What is reason have to use compatibility mode in first place?

Comment: No results are possible.